# nested series in highcharts drilldown

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I am trying to use [highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/)' drilldown with nested series. To keep things simple, I am using the official demo provided by highcharts.js:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/drilldown/multi-series/

```
drilldown: {
        series: [{
            id: 'republican-2010',
            data: [
                ['East', 4],
                ['West', 2],
                ['North', 1],
                ['South', 4]
            ]
```

I would like to modify this example to also compare election years in the drilldown. The official demo's drilldown only shows a single election year for each region (north, south, etc). I would like to have the same blue/black columns (election year) in the drilldown graphs.

My attempts of nesting series in drilldowns are found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/draptik/bnvbsLd1/1/

```
drilldown: {
  series: [{
    id: 'republican-2010',
    data: [{
      series: [{
        name: 'republican',
        data: [{
          name: 'north',
          y: 3
        }, {
          name: 'west',
          y: 3
        }, {
          name: 'east',
          y: 3
        }, {
          name: 'south',
          y: 3
        }]
      }, {
        name: 'democrat',
```

Basically I just tried to nest a series in the drilldown's series data array, but this does not work.

Thankful for any pointer.

Comment: what do you mean? at the x axis you want to print out "Republicans 2010 - Republicans 2014"?

Comment: @mrapsogos yes, I would like to have the same x axis (but with 'north', 'south') and the same columns in the drilldown as in the main plot.

Comment: Hi, I think that good idea in your case is to use grouped-categories Highcharts plugin: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

Here you can find an example of chart that works with this plugin: http://jsfiddle.net/TFhd7/850/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Thanks for the pointer to the grouped-categories plugin! This is not quite what I am looking for, but I'll keep it in mind for future layout options. As it seems a drilldown can't contain a collection of series I'll just link to a new page.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I think that Highcharts can have collection of series. You will get  chart similar to what you are trying to achieve by clicking on category, not single column. You can also see this example: http://jsfiddle.net/49q18Lp3/6/

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński Wow, very cool, that is exactly what I was looking for: thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove series property inside drilldown's data.
It'll be like this:

```
    drilldown: {
      series: [
        {
          id: 'republican-2010',
          data: [{
            name: 'republican',
            y: 10,
            drilldown: 'repbulican'
          }]
        }, // end of first series
        {
          id: 'repbulican',
          data: [
           ['north' , 3],
           ['west' , 3],
           ['east', 3],
           ['south', 3]
          ]
        }
       ] // end of series array
      } // end of drilldown object
```

I already made an example for 'republican-2010' series only to show you how to do it.

Just do the same for other series.